# Distance to, travel only on one surface

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, distance, spatial-analyst

Looking to create a distance to wetland raster. However this travel distance must be through the water only.

I have tried setting land to a high cost (e.g. 99) however doing so I have to set each water cell to its own "cost" however I don't want to calculate relative cost, I want the actual distance in Metres.

Comment: are you looking to create routes, or simply assign each each cell around a wetland it's distance to the nearest wetland?

Comment: I am looking to assign each cell its distance from the wetland, however if for example there is an island between the cell and the wetland, the distance would include going around the island.

Comment: Set travel cost through river cell equal cell size. Set ground cells much higher. Compute travel distance to outlet TOTAL. Convert river cells to destination raster. Calculate travel distance to stream. See if difference of 2 results is what you are after

Answer (score 1):

Create a Cost surface where your wetlands and the water area get the value 1 and all the other areas shall be NoData or extreme vals like 100,000. After that you can create an Cost Distance surface from your wetlands on the Cost Surface. Done. If the Cost Surface value is 1, the Cost Distance values will be map units. [Cost Distance interpretation in ArcGIS 10.2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138158/cost-distance-interpretation-in-arcgis-10-2/138238#138238)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear from your question whether you're looking at cost paths or just a straight distance raster. In either case you probably need to create a [mask raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w0000001t000000) and use that in whichever tool you're wanting or as an environment setting. You can use [Con](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000005000000) to create a mask that is/is not land, then use that mask as a parameter in the other tools to that it ignores anything in/out of the mask.