# Generate Near Table (path distance)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance

I have a number of points and want to get path distance to all "wetland" polygons within 1km. This is very easy with eucDistance in Generate near table, is there a was to alter this to give path distance instead?

Comment: What path? Along a network or do you just have specific barriers you want to use? This could be done with masks or with Path Distance / Cost Raster tools. I don't think you'll get around going to raster to do this analysis, or at least that's the easiest/first way that comes to mind. I can't think of a vector way without having a network to measure along since there's an infinite number of paths to take from A to B.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. The idea is that I have a land/water raster and I need the path to only exist on the water (land is classified as NoData). I would just need the shortest distance to each polygon within 1000m. To me it seems I will have to do this manually for each point and that is fine. Was just hopeing there would be a way to do it for a large number of points. Thanks again.

Comment: So isn't this basically a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139768/ then? If you want the distances from each point to all wetlands within 1km, you would have to do them one at a time/with an iterative model. If you tried to do all points at once you'd only get the distance to the nearest wetlands - ie if there is a point between another point and a wetland within 1k of the first you don't get that total distance, just from the nearest point.